# Long time behaviour of inhomogeneous wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have been given the following wave equation:

$$u_{tt}(x,t) = c^2u_{xx}(x,t)-ru_t(x,t)+g(x)\sin(\omega t)$$

where $t >0, x\in (0,l)$ and $g: [0,l] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is in $L^2$. All the parameters are  greater zero. Given initial values $u = u_t = 0 \ , \ t=0$ as well as homogeneous boundary conditions: $u(0,t) = u(l,t) = 0$   .I would like to find out the following:

For which values of $\omega$ does the solution grow over time $t$ , when $r = 0$ and for which values $\omega$ when $r > 0$? I am not quite sure how to tackle this problem. In the first case, i.e. $r=0$, I thought I might find an explicit solution but I do not think that this is the best way to solve this, since in the second case I would not be able to find any solution.

I do not necessarily need a complete solution, but any hints or help on how this could be approached would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried taking Fourier series (in x only)? In that way you should get second order inhomogeneous ODEs in t and they are solvable.

Comment: You probably have a Dirichlet boundary condition (or some other boundary condition) at $x=0, x=l$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, I forgot to mention that - I updated the question

Comment: @ydx In the second case this might get messy but I will give this a try - thanks!

Comment: In steps: 
1. Use an eigenfunction on $u(x,t)$ to eventually write out a ODE for the coefficients in the fourier series as a function of $t$ (say $a_n(t)$). 

2. You will then only need to discuss the behavior of this second order ODE. An explicit solution isn't completely necessary, but you do like two thirds of it.

Comment: The $r=0$ case is far easier than the $r>0$ case, you also get a completely different solution assuming $r^2 < \left( \frac{n \pi c}{2} \right)^2$....